# incorrect peer dependency with redux-form and reat-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, yarnpkg

Whenever I  run yarn install `yarn install` with the following package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "immutable": "3.8.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "promise": "7.1.1",
    "react-fontawesome": "1.6.1",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-fontawesome": "1.6.1",
    "redux": "3.7.1",
    "redux-api": "0.10.8",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-form": "^7.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "2.2.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
  },
```

I get the following warning:

```
warning "ajv-keywords@1.5.1" has incorrect peer dependency "ajv@>=4.10.0".
warning "redux-form@7.0.4" has incorrect peer dependency "react-redux@^4.3.0 || ^5.0.0".
```

I don't understand why it is complaining about `react-redux@^4.3.0 || ^5.0.0` when I am referencing `react-redux@5.0.6`.

Comment: those warnings are related to packages themselves. They have strict dependencies. Opening up an issue on github pages would help to notice them and get an update on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Pull Request #3803](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/3803) introduced this behavior in fixing [Bug #3710](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3710) where peer dependencies were only being resolved from their siblings and the repository root, but not higher-levels. Modules at different directory levels referencing the the same code could require different versions. [Pull Request #4478](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/4478) ([code change here](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/commit/a1ab4b3e2c3964aec5db262ee195230ed29c72db)) updated yarns logic to resolve peer dependencies from higher levels.

Update Yarn along with your packages and you should stop seeing the error.

Also, avoid using the [npm upgrade](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3042#issuecomment-310923650) command to get the latest version of yarn - use npm install.

```
npm install -g yarn
```